# Angular : How to handle the async set of a variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

Under my **Angular 6** app , i have this service ; where i'm declaring a varibale called **permittedPefs** , this variable is setted asychronsouly within a `httpClient.get` call.

```
@Injectable()
    export class myService implements OnInit {

      permittedPefs = [];
      constructor(){}

      ngOnInit() {
      // STEP 1
      this.loadUserPefsService.getUserRolePefs(roleId).subscribe(
          (returnedListPefs) => {
            this.permittedPefs = returnedListPefs;
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
      // STEP 2
      this.myMethod(1);
```

After that , i ve a call of this method which is using my **-supposed setted -** var

```
myMethod(pefId): boolean {
        return this.permittedPefs.includes(pefId);
}
```

the problem is it seems that **permittedPefs** , haven't got its value yet , and the call of `myMethod()` point to a wrong value of "**permittedPefs**"

So what's the simpliest way **to make it wait to the just after the http response** , without calling if from the http Response callback *(as i 'm using it in several places)*

***Sugesstions??***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynchronous Hell ! the best choice here is to get an `Observable` instead of a value

in your service :

```
getValue (): Observable<any>{

return this.loadUserPefsService.getUserRolePefs(roleId);

}
```

in your method :

```
 myMethod(pefId): boolean {

       this.yourservice.getValue().subscribe(
       data => {

         if(data){
            return data.includes(pefId);
             }

        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the method `this.myMethod(1);` from `subscription` block, so that you wait for asynchronous call to be completed, which will then set the value of `permittedPefs`.

```
ngOnInit() {
      // STEP 1
      this.loadUserPefsService.getUserRolePefs(roleId).subscribe(
          (returnedListPefs) => {
            this.permittedPefs = returnedListPefs;
           // STEP 2
           this.myMethod(1);  // check this line
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
}
```

Comment: i ve already noticed that i won't do it that way : as my call of method may be in several places and within other methods

Comment: Well at least the first call inside `ngOnInIt()` should be this way as shown. So you will have the value of `permittedPefs` by that time. Later you can call the method `this.myMethod(1)` from other places as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your method is called when you have not received the result yet. so  just move the function call in subscribe function